# Use active application in fullscreen mode (not maximized)

Tags: windows, fullscreen, virtual-desktop

With my FullHD monitor I use application bar fixed to right. That way I have good overview of other applications and their switching is easy. Sometimes I use applications that need lot of space (Photoshop for example).

I know I can temporarily switch application bar to slide away, but that is not very convenient. I am looking for program that on hotkey either switches between virtual desktops, or (preferably) turns active application to full screen mode (similar to medial players, overlaying anything on screen).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found this solution to fulfill my expectations.

1. Installed [Dexpot](http://dexpot.de/) virtual desktop.
2. Set up two desktops, HOME with usual settings and FULL with taskbar turned off.
3. In Dexpot settings **Assign applications** I have assigned some applications to use FULL desktop.

When I launch application I want to be full screen, it goes to FULL desktop automatically.

With some helpers - shortcuts (Alt+1, Alt+2) and hot corners in MouseEvents plugin it is very comfortable to switch between desktops.